# cannot access the classes in the package

Tags: java, package

I have the following directory structure :

`MessManagement` is the parent directory.

Under that i have 3 directories :
`student` , `messconvener`,`messmanager`

The student directory contains the `Student.java` and `Student.class` files. The `messconvener` contains the `MessConvener.java` this requires the `Student class` as `MessConvener` **is extended** from `Student` itself.

How should i do the packaging of the classes....??

What i have tried so far.

Code :

This is `Student.java`

```
package MessManagement;
import java.sql.*;

public class Student
{

}
```

This is `MessConvener.java`

```
package MessManagement;
import MessManagement.student.Student;
public class MessConvener extends Student
{

}
```

But this does not seem to work.Error Meesage :

`MessConvener.java:2: error: package MessManagement.student does not exist
import MessManagement.student.Student;
                             ^
MessConvener.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class MessConvener extends Student
                                  ^
  symbol: class Student
2 errors`

Comment: What IDE are you utilizing?

Comment: i am using terminal in ubuntu

Comment: How do you compile this?  Looking at your error message, I think it is a simple classpath issue.  You need to specify your classpath in your javac command when you try to compile it.

Comment: post your code to here.. so we can help you better..

Comment: did you first compile the Student.java class before compiling MessConvener.java class?

Comment: @beyonddc i compile it using javac.

Comment: @RobinSaxena i have already compiled Student.java

Comment: this seems to be a problem with Intellij IDEA (rsp. the usage). had this problem twice today, could fix it in the maven project with smac89 help, and now i got it in the other (gradle) project, too. Happened when I copied some classes from one project to the other. very odd behaviour.

Comment: In Intellij, try [Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > You can choose only Invalidate and restart.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549649/java-cannot-access-class-class-file-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons why this happens

1. Is the root of your directories included in the classpath? You need to specify when starting a java program. [See the documentation on how to do that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) or [this variant for unix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html).
2. Are your classes public? If you forget the public modifier, classes will have package visibility and cannot be accessed from other packages.
3. Oh well, nobody expects the spanish inquisition ... check your spelling carefully, including capitals.

Comment: how do i include the classpath..?

Comment: in my case since Im on windows the file which was accessing this class was LF and the class which was imported was in CRLF format.

Answer (score 17):

The error you're getting makes sense. The `Student` class is located in `MessManagement` package not `MessManagement.student` package.

So either remove your import of `Student` in `MessManagement` or change the package name in `Student` to `MessManagement.student`.

---

For me, I got this error for a different reason and this was in a maven project. It began to occur after I made major changes to the classes and copied in a lot of new classes. There were no conflicting package names as in your case.

The solution was to do `mvn clean`.

After this, I didn't get that error anymore.

Comment: thanks for the Maved hint! I also copied some classes. It was sufficient to click blue Maven refresh button in IntelliJ ("Reimport All Maven Projects")

Comment: ok mvn clean was a super tip, as soon as I opened the terminal inside IntelliJ to type mvn clean, IntelliJ suddenly recovered itself and started recognizing my classes...

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this issue and it was because I had a class file in the same directory as the java file that I was compiling. You need to delete all .class files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I am literally 8 years late, but today I had this problem and I managed to solve it just re-writing the state of the class. Seems that if you comitted your project, pulling it back could make you have that problem, but writing again the "public" state of your class worked for me. I Hope it works for you guys. chrss.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the [out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hm8Z.png) folder and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened after updating java to jdk_16.

it was solved after I changed the "misc.xml" file inside ".idea" folder.
changed languageLevel="JDK_15" to languageLevel="JDK_16".

Answer (score 0):

In `Intellij`, try

1. Go to File
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart
3. You can choose only Invalidate and restart

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549649/java-cannot-access-class-class-file-not-found)