# Java cannot access class, class file not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, jaxb

When I try to make a project in IntelliJ I receive the following error on this line:

```
Sentence sent = new Sentence();
 sent.emptySegments();
```

Error:

```
Error:(151, 10) java: cannot access javax.xml.bind.RootElement
class file for javax.xml.bind.RootElement not found
```

`Sentence` is a class which implements the `RootElement` **interface**

```
import javax.xml.bind.RootElement;
...
public class Sentence extends MarshallableRootElement implements RootElement   {
```

All packages exist and I can jump to declaration of each interface or class but I don't know why IntellJ says it cannot access or find them? However `RootElement` is an interface and not a class

```
public interface RootElement extends Element {
    void validate() throws StructureValidationException;
}
```

The above declaration is in a jar file named `jaxb-rt-1.0-ea.jar` and it exists in the Project librarians.

Comment: To ask the obvious, is the `jaxb-rt-1.0-ea.jar` added to your project dependencies at build time?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I solved it, I added the jar file to Module dependencies which had the error

Comment: This is what I was guessing the problem was.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, the complete answer is bellow in my answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The project contained several modules. While the library was added to the project libraries, some modules lacked it in their dependency part. So I solved the problem using the following steps in IntelliJ

Creating a module library and adding it to the module dependencies:

1. Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
2. In the left-hand pane of the dialog, select Modules.
3. In the pane to the right, select the module of interest.
4. In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Module page, select the Dependencies tab.
5. On the Dependencies tab, click + (on the top right) and select Jars or directories.
6. In the dialog that opens, select the necessary files and folders. These may
   be individual .class and .java files, directories and archives
   (.jar and .zip) containing such files as well as directories with
   Java native libraries (.dll, .so or .jnilib).
7. Click OK. If necessary,    select the Export option and change the dependency scope.
8. Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: why I have make this?

Comment: For me, compilation was running fine but In my project, the IDE was showing with a red underline. I found that the dependency was marked as Runtime scope. Once i made the module dependency scope Compile, it removed the red underline.

Comment: May be, it is workaround to fix the intellij issue. Thanks

Answer (score 127):

Try this

1. Go to File
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart
3. You can choose only Invalidate and restart

(See *[Invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html)* on IntelliJ's manual)

Comment: Sometimes Intellij just be DumbJ. Worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart
this worked for my after long hours of effectiveless

Answer (score 9):

Rebuilding project worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the `.idea` folder and then running `Invalidate Caches/Restart` worked for me.

Comment: Just invalidating caches/restart worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It also may be because you don't have dependencies in classpath, which used in dependencies.
*For example*: you use library A, but class you're using from A has superclass from library B. But you didn't add B to classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single file, you can try deleting the file and undoing it. It seems to reindex that particular file alone, which is much faster than **Invalidate Caches/Restart**. As a precautionary measure, you can take a backup of the file before deleting, just in case if something goes awry.

Another reason might be different versions of same library with more/less methods. This happened for me with Gradle. Sometimes it compiles fine and sometimes, it doesn't. Just find and remove the unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

My Gradle/IntelliJ "big hammer"

(Optional, but preferred).  Close all instances of IntelliJ or any other Java IDE.

delete the ".idea" folder (<< intellij specific, or whatever "workspace" folder your IDE uses)

..............

```
./gradlew --stop       
      OR
gradle --stop
```

(now delete the folders)

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/build-cache-tmp/
```

(now resume normal gradlew commands like:)

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just worked, turn off windows defender / add exclusion project folder / idea process.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem can happen if a library is imported with maven scope *runtime*.

In such case it isn't accessible by your classes located under `src/main/java`.

Only classes in `src/test/java` can directly use *runtime* dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this location "amazonaws" file and clean install later run

```
/Users/testuser/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've made it this far because rebuilding or invalidating the cache didn't work work you, I found that deleting the class and adding a new one with the same code worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an old .iml file in the module causing these problems. So if nothing else worked for you, try looking for one.

Answer (score -1):

⬇ [Download](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) the last version of IntelliJ.

▶ Install it.

Worked for me. ✌