# Failed XSD Generation From Java Class In IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, schema

I have IntelliJ Ultimate and, while trying to generate a XSD file from a Java Class, I get the follwing error:
[image]

What could be the issue ?. I installed the corresponding plugin but it doesnt seem to find the class..

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549649/java-cannot-access-class-class-file-not-found help?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).