# IntelliJ "FileNotFoundException" | Only in Debug-Mode

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ, however as soon as I try do debug it, it throws a FileNotFoundExcpetion. The file /.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/jaxb-core.jar can not be found. And indeed the file is missing.

I am assuming it has something to do with Maven, but I can not figure out what.
If I run the project without Debug-Mode activated, it works fine.

Comment: Please see if the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312963/924036 helps.

Comment: Can you compile and run from the command line using the `mvn` command?

Comment: @KajHejer unfortunately not.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have run mvn clean install. It finishes without problems.

Comment: Set up so exec:run works.

Comment: I have now reimported the project and deleted my local repository. It is now working again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a problem with my Maven configuration. I deleted the /.m2/repository directory and ran `mvn clean install` again. This fixed the problem.