# Java Arraylist Cannot Access Class Objects

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist, scope

I have been writing a program in IntellJ IDEA (Latest Community Version) to store new users of an application into a array list titled users.

For some reason my arraylist cannot access my User class.

My Main Class:

```
public class Main {

List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.makeUser();

}

public void makeUser() {

    //makes new User
    User user = new User();
    System.out.println("Username: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    //sets username to input
    user.username = input;
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    //sets password to new input
    user.password = input;

    addUser(user);
}

private void addUser(User user){
    // adds a new user to an Arraylist

     users.add(user);
    user.setUserIndex(users.size() - 1);
}
```

}

My User Class:

```
public class User {
String username;
String password;
String email;

int userIndex;
boolean loggedIn;

// Getters
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}
public int getUserIndex(){
    return userIndex;
}

//Setters
public void setUserIndex(int index){
    userIndex = index;
}
public void setPassword(String pass){
    password = pass;
}
public void setEmail(String eMail){
    email = eMail;
}
public void setLoggedIn(boolean status){
    loggedIn = status;
}
```

}

The line "users.add(user)" in the addUser() method is flagged and the exact error reads: Cannot access User.

Why is my arraylist users unable to access User when everything is public? Should I be using something different to store users or is this a problem with scope?

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: With the code you've posted, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. See if this solves your problem - [Java cannot access class, class file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549649/java-cannot-access-class-class-file-not-found)

Comment: If you post the question as a answer I will click the check.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you used single java file with these 2 class definitions.

**You have 2 options:**

1. change public class User defintion into  class User (remove
   public keyword)
2. Please move User Class definition into seperate file.

Please check whether you imported Java util classes . if not done yet, please add below statement.

import java.util.*;

**Rootcause:** We should have only 1 public class in any java file

Please refer https://dzone.com/articles/why-single-java-source-file-can-not-have-more-than

**corrected code based on Option1:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    List<User1> users = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.makeUser();

    }

    public void makeUser() {

        //makes new User
        User1 user = new User1();
        System.out.println("Username: ");
        input = scanner.nextLine();

        //sets username to input
        user.username = input;
        System.out.println("Password: ");
        input = scanner.nextLine();

        //sets password to new input
        user.password = input;

        addUser(user);
    }

    private void addUser(User1 user){
        // adds a new user to an Arraylist

        users.add(user);
        user.setUserIndex(users.size() - 1);
    }
}

class User {
    String username;
    String password;
    String email;

    int userIndex;
    boolean loggedIn;

    // Getters
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    public int getUserIndex(){
        return userIndex;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setUserIndex(int index){
        userIndex = index;
    }
    public void setPassword(String pass){
        password = pass;
    }
    public void setEmail(String eMail){
        email = eMail;
    }
    public void setLoggedIn(boolean status){
        loggedIn = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that only one class in the file was allowed to be public.